# Is there an HTML date time input with format "yyy-mm-dd hh-mm-ss"?

Tags: php, html, datetime

I tried printing using this:

```
<input type="datetime-local" id="sales_date_time" name="sales_date_time">
```

but it prints with a T and server wont accept that format as I have set `datetime` format in it:

`2020-07-01T20:39`

So, it expects this format:

```
2019-12-03 07:12:29
```

Any suggestions how to implement this?

Comment: Several approaches in the linked duplicate. I prefer the ones that use `DateTime::createFromFormat`, personally.

Comment: @ceejayoz thanks, howveer, how would you convert this format `2020-07-01T20:39` into this `2020-07-01 20:39:00` . I couldn't find it there in th link provided

Comment: ("2020-07-01T20:39").replace('T',' ')

Comment: you can also use like this : https://jsfiddle.net/nikleshraut/c9k7ywaz/2/

Comment: @ttt You would use `createFromFormat` to do that.